# Pandas-Datareder does not load Google Finance data

Tags: python, datareader, google-finance

I am trying to download Google Finance data through `pandas_datareader`.

When I execute:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime(2018, 1, 2)
end = datetime(2018, 10, 12)
ms = web.DataReader('MS', 'google', start, end)
x = f.iloc[:,3]
print (x)
```

I get the following:

> RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=MS&startdate=Jan+02%2C+2018&enddate=Oct+12%2C+2018&output=csv
>   Response Text:
>   `b'<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><title>Sorry...</title><style> body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; }</style></head><body><div><table><tr><td><b><font face=sans-serif size=10><font color=#4285f4>G</font><font color=#ea4335>o</font><font color=#fbbc05>o</font><font color=#4285f4>g</font><font color=#34a853>l</font><font color=#ea4335>e</font></font></b></td><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">Sorry...</div></td></tr></table></div><div style="margin-left: 4em;"><h1>We\'re sorry...</h1><p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can\'t process your request right now.</p></div><div style="margin-left: 4em;">See <a href="https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Google Help</a> for more information.<br/><br/></div><div style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google Home</a></div></body></html>'`

How can I access the data without getting into this? 
Also, please notice that using other APIs, such as IEX, the datareader worked fine (just Google Finance has wider availability of data).

Answer (score 0):

The Google Finance endpoints which were used in Pandas Datareader have been [discontinued](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/555#issuecomment-416266722). As such, Google Finance has been [deprecated](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/537) (marked for removal) as of the current Pandas Datareader version (0.7.0).

You are likely using an earlier verison of Pandas Datareader, which is why using the `google` data source of `web.DataReader` raises a `RemoteDataError` instead of an `ImmediateDeprecationError`.

To solve your problem, I would recommend using a different data source, such as [IEX](https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/stable/remote_data.html#iex):

`ms = web.DataReader("ms", "iex", start, end)`

other options include [Alpha Vantage](https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/stable/remote_data.html#alpha-vantage) and [Quandl](https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/stable/remote_data.html#quandl).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the following code to pull daily stock prices by using 'yahoo'. Here is the code.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as data

ticker = input(str("Enter ticker: "))
data_source = 'yahoo'
start = dt.datetime(2017, 1 ,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020, 1 ,12)
df= data.DataReader(ticker, data_source, start, end)
```